# Vector spaces-span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be the set of all $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$ which satisfy

$2x_1-x_2+\frac{4}{3}x_3-x_4=0$

$x_1+\frac{2}{3}x_3-x_5=0$

$9x_1-3x_2+6x_3-3x_4-3x_5=0$.

Find a finite set of vectors which spans $W$?

This question is from  linear algebra Hoffman and K. Guys please help in this question I don't know what to do in this question.

Comment: This is a linear system. Do you know how to use Gaussian elimination to put it in Reduced Row Echelon Form? That's a standard way to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

As Julien mentions, write it in matrix form and do Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form (RREF).

$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & \frac{4}{3} & -1 & 0\\1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & -1 \\ 9 & -3 & 6 & -3 & -3\end{bmatrix}$

The RREF produces:

$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -2\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Do you know how to proceed?

**Update**

From the RREF, you now know that the system has a solution and is thus consistent.

That is, you can solve the RREF system (you know how - do it, but don't need to for this problem).

This means that those two vectors span (know which ones) $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Recommendation: It is important for you to review what span means as that might be confusing you (I am guessing), but you should you understand this concept.

Comment: Ok i understood upto this.Then how will i get finite set of vectors which span W

Comment: @DavidJones: see update.

Comment: Nice work, and nice extra help with the update! +1